# Retrieve images from database to listview. Thumbnail View

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

This is the code to retrieve images from specific folder and display it in a list-view. It displays the images in large icons but I want to retrieve the images from a database.

Here is the code:

```
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
   'retrieve image from specific folder
    Dim dirFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("D:\Capture")
    Dim _imgList As New ImageList
    Dim imgSize As New Size
   'setting up custom size
    imgSize.Width = 155
    imgSize.Height = 255
    ListView1.LargeImageList = _imgList
    ListView1.LargeImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    For Each dirFile As String In dirFiles
        Dim imgFilename As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dirFile)
        Dim img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(dirFile)
        Dim imgImage As Image = Image.FromFile(dirFile)
        _imgList.ImageSize = imgSize
        _imgList.Images.Add(img.Clone)
        ListView1.Items.Add(imgFilename, count)
        count += 1
    Next
```

The tutorials I tried does not work because the images is converted into a byte array before saving it to the database, In my work I am saving the path of the images. Anyone can help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do save images or image file names?

Comment: i'm saving the image paths with its filename, not the image itself.

Comment: i can already save the image path. my problem is how to retrieve it with the code above

Comment: that code is iterating files in a folder. it isnt using a filename read from a database.

Comment: that's why I'm asking for help, the code show where i am at.

Comment: `Image.FromFile(FileNameReadFromDatabase)`